# No getting steady reading from iBeacon

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am trying to experiment with ibeacon and this is this is the area of my code that is responsible for displaying the beacon signal

```
    func startScanning() {
    let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDString: "FDA50693-A4E2-4FB1-AFCF-C6EB07647825")!
    let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: 10004, minor: 5178, identifier: "MyBeacon")
    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion)
}

func updateDistance(distance: CLProximity) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) { [unowned self] in
        switch distance {
        case .Unknown:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "No Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Far:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Weak Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Near:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Medium Beacon Signal Detected"

        case .Immediate:
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            self.distanceReading.text = "Strong Beacon Signal Detected"
        }
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beacons.count > 0 {
        let beacon = beacons[0]
        updateDistance(beacon.proximity)
    } else {
        updateDistance(.Unknown)
    }
}
```

The problem I have is let say I place the beacon about 12  inches away from my cell phone, it shows "Medium Beacon Signal Detected", then 5, 10, or maybe 15 secs later shows "No Beacon Signal Detected" and then a sec later shows again "Medium Beacon Signal Detected". This cycle continues. Also once in a while I see "Weak Beacon Signal Detected",

So my question is if I am not touching the beacon, shouldn't alway show me "Medium Beacon Signal Detected" and not switch between Weak and no signal?

Could it be because I ordered a cheap beacon from China for experimenting purpose? I checked the battery and is 100% full. I wonder what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intermittent detections are often caused by beacons that transmit infrequently.**  For best results when ranging, beacons should send out at least 10 packets per second.  Some "cheap" beacons will cut down on the number of transmissions to one packet every 5 seconds (or even less often) to save battery.

There is no way with iOS to tell exactly how many advertisements per second the beacon is transmitting.  You'd have to ask the beacon supplier or get a bluetooth sniffer device to find out for sure.

Bottom line:  what you are seeing is not normal with a properly operating beacon.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That make sense.